# How to cite it properly?

Tags: citing

What is the correct way to cite the following:

```
[2, and the references therein] [see also 13,15,33]
```

Should there be a comma after see also? And what is the command to produce it?

Comment: I probably would prefer to use parentheses, i.e. (see also [13,15,33])`(see also \cite{ref1, ref2, ref3})`

Comment: As @Alex said, and the whole aside *not* inside the first ref: [2] and the references therein (see also [13,15,33]). But alas, I cannot claim any authority on this issue other than gut feeling (my gut can be quite assertive sometimes).

Comment: `[2, and the references therein]` conventionally refers to the study [2] and in it the Section, Chapter, or Theorem etc. which is called *and the references therein*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The package [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) redefines the `\cite`command with optional arguments that do exactly what you are asking for. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{Author2012,
    Author = {Author, A},
    Title = {Article},
    Year = {2012}}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\cite{Author2012}

\cite[e.g.]{Author2012}

\cite[see][]{Author2012}

\cite[and references therein]{Author2012}

\cite[see][and references therein]{Author2012}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

If you prefer author-year citation style, you can remove the `[numbers]` option when loading the package, and you can replace the square brackets by round brackets with the option `[round]`.

Comment: Some of that is also possible without `natbib`: `\cite[Ch.~1]{Author2012}` gives [1, Ch. 1] and `\cite[p.~387]{Author2012}` gives [1, p. 387]. Any words not relating to the citation should be kept outside the square brackets, see @percusse's comment above.